# SVN Update issue

Tags: python, eclipse, svn, eclipse-juno

I Used eclipse juno latest version and installed svn from market place.its upto yesterday worked perfectly.but from yesterday evening its not updated whole files.only some files updated.

```
update /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl -r HEAD --force
    Restored /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/__init__.py
    Restored /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/__openerp__.py
    Restored /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/bpl.py
    Restored /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/bpl_estate_allowance.py
    Restored /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/bpl_estate_deduction.py
    Restored /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/bpl_individual_allowance.py
    Restored /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/bpl_individual_deduction.py
    Restored /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/bpl_master_allowance.py
    Restored /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/bpl_master_deduction.py
    Restored /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/bpl_view.xml
    Restored /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/bpl_worker_registration_sequence.xml
    Restored /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/company_view.xml
    Restored /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/estate_allowance.xml
    Restored /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/estate_deduction.xml
    Restored /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/individual_allowance.xml
    Restored /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/individual_deduction.xml
    Restored /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/master_allowance.xml
    Restored /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/master_deduction.xml
    Restored /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/notes
    Restored /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/security
    Restored /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/security/bpl_security.xml
    Restored /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/security/ir.model.access.csv
    U   /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/bpl.py
    U   /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/bpl_view.xml
    U   /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/security/ir.model.access.csv
    Updated to revision 59070.
    ===== File Statistics: =====
    Updated: 3
revert -N /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/static
revert -N /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/static/src
revert -N /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/static/src/css
revert -N /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/static/src/css/bpl.css
revert -N /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/static/src/img
revert -N /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/static/src/img/icon.png
revert -N /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/static/src/js
revert -N /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/static/src/js/bpl_js.js
update  -r HEAD --force
    svn: E200009: Wrong number of targets has been specified (0), at least 1 is required.
    svn: E200009: Wrong number of targets has been specified (0), at least 1 is required.
```

please advice me to sort out this issue

Now issue is like below.popup dialog box from eclipse

```
Could not remove /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/static/src/css/bpl.css
Could not remove /home/bellvantage/software/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/static/src/css/bpl.css
```

Answer (score 2):

cd to the directory where your source files are and try:

> svn revert --recursive .

(Don't miss the dot)

Comment: Then it seems like the meta files that save svn related information are corrupted. Your best bet might be to do an rm -rf on the directory and checkout a fresh copy of code, using: svn co <svn path>

Comment: First I tried to solve this problem in Eclipse using Team /  Refresh/Cleanup - did not help. But "svn revert --recursive ."   did help

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it will solve your problem, but sometimes svn is no more "synchronized" with my workspace. I solve this problem with a refresh of the project (F5) and then Team/Cleanup.
After that I can retry the operation that was blocking.

Update: If all your commits are done, you can try to replace your project. If you need to commit, take a backup of the files and try to commit. If it doesn't work replace your project and then copy the files you want to commmit from your backup. You need maybe to delete your project.

When you synchronize your workspace you avoid problem if you follow this order :

1. Resolve your conflicts.
2. Commit your changes.
3. Update your workspace.

If you first update your workspace, sometimes svn try to resolve conflicts but fails and create temporary files. In this case you need to resolve the conflict with Team/Edit conflicts or Team/Mark Resolved but it is more complicated.